# Reading POST body: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed

Tags: spring-webflux

In Spring Webflux, when I read a POST body, and try to work with it, it always results in the IllegalStateException from the title.

Here the code:

```
  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> selectByPost(SasoSecurityFacade solrHandler) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.POST("/v1/{collection}/select")
                                     .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), request -> request.bodyToMono(String.class)
        .flatMap(s -> {
          System.out.println(s);
          return ServerResponse.ok()
              .syncBody(s);
        }));
  }
```

Also important (as it turns out), the request TO the server:

```
curl 'https://<myserver>:9443/v1/banana-int/select' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://<myserver>:9443' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: https://<myserver>:9443/banana/src/index.html' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data 'q=*:*&rows=20&wt=json' --compressed
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I debug this? Who else is reading my post body, so that I get this error message?

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot application? Is that the full handler definition (it seems you're injecting something here you're not using)? Do you have `WebFilter` instances configured? What does the request look like? Does this happen only on that path or also on other request paths?

Comment: I already put some work in this (several days, actually, since this seems not debuggable): No webfilters, it's spring-boot, the request is a quite short string like "q=*:*&rows=20&wt=json".  The only thing left is trying to do everything from scratch.

Comment: Then there must be something at play here that is not obvious, since copying/pasting this code snippet in a Spring Boot application works for me. Do you have a repro project I can take a look at?

Comment: Could you answer my previous question and show a curl command of the request you're making to the server?

Comment: I found the problem, replace `request.bodyToMono(String.class)` with `request.formData()`...

Comment: This is what chrome makes of the request that's used by my angular webapplication (minus cookies, since it's too long); I suspect the content-type beeing the cause for my grief: `curl 'https://<myserver>:9443/v1/banana-int/select' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'  -H 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data 'q=*:*&rows=20&wt=json' --compressed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request you're sending is a POST Form request, which is automatically read by `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`. This filter is consuming the form data to mutate the HTTP method in case an alternate method is specified through a `"_method"` parameter.

In this case, consuming the form data with the dedicated `request.formData()` API in WebFlux annotation/functional is the best choice, this it is cached for future use and does not trigger a new subscription.

If you wish to completely disable this behavior, [you'll be able to set a property in Spring Boot 2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14520).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the dedicated part? You mean add something like this: `RequestPredicates.contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`?

Comment: no, the API you're using now as edited in your comments. I've edited my answer.